# Rearrange and regroup stacked data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have Excel data as follows:

```
Mon  34
Mon  76
Mon  86
Tue  24
Tue  34
Tue  66
Wed  88
Wed  89
Wed  87
```

Is there a way with a formula to rewrite this data as follows:

```
Mon   Tue   Wed
34    24    88
76    66    89
86    66    87
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `76` is in B2, insert a column on the left and a row above. Label the columns (say `ID`, `day` and `value`) and in A2 enter `1` and series fill down to A4. Then select A2:A4 and series fill down to suit.

Build a PivotTable with `ID` for ROWS, `day` for COLUMNS and `value` for VALUES.

Won't give quite the result you show from the data sample:

[image: SO28183043 example]